# Error importing csv data into Neo4j where the header contains spaces

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Little new to Neo4j so maybe this is a little stupid but I have searched high and low to find and answer

I am trying to import data from a .csv that has spaces in the headers. I can import the file just fine but when I reference the rows in the cypher statement I get an error.

To demonstrate, if I run the following cypher query the 100 rows are displayed / returned just fine

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///AppDataOrig.csv" AS row with row limit 100 return row
```

If I then try the following

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///AppDataOrig.csv" AS row with row limit 1 
with row.'Device Name' as device
return device
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid input ''': expected an identifier, whitespace, a function name or a 
property key name (line 2, column 10 (offset: 87))
"with row.'Device Name' as device"
```

It does not like the quoted `Device Name` but if I leave out the quotes it does not like the space

I have seen this done in videos, but don't know where I am going wrong - perhaps this is just not supported any more?

Answer (score 14):

Use the backtick (`) to quote names containing unusual characters (like non-alphanumeric characters or spaces). For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///AppDataOrig.csv" AS row
RETURN row.`Device Name` AS device
LIMIT 1;
```